# PIC16F84A Instruction BSF - Assembly

Tags: assembly, pic

I am using the instruction `bsf PORTB,COUNT`to set a certain bit to 1 . In this instruction the address of `COUNT` is taken , I need to take the content of `COUNT` for example 6 or 7 , how can i do it ? I am new to this Assembly code

Comment: I'm not at my system; this is from (very) hazy memory. See if this works: `Mov  [COUNT], W0` then `BSF W0, PORTB` Again, No promise on any of this. Somebody smarter please chime in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first operand of the BSF is the target address of the operation, in your case PORTB. The second operand is the bit number to be set (0 to 7) specified by a constant.

The assembler interpreted the address label COUNT as a constant which was not what you intended to do.

One solution when a second register contains the bit number is to generate a bitmask for the bit number and then bitwise OR the target register with that mask.

To generate the bitmask load a register with 1 and then shift it left the bit number of times. So for bit 0 you would not shift at all (00000001), for bit 7 you would shift left 7 times (resulting in 10000000). The masks can be pre-calculated, stored in memory, and indexed into by the bit number as needed.